# nature of SELECT query in MVC and LINQ TO SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i am bit confused by the nature and working of query , I tried to access database which contains each name more than once having same EMPid so when i accessed it in my DROP DOWN LIST then same repetition was in there too so i tried to remove repetition by putting DISTINCT in query but that didn't work but later i modified it another way and that worked but **WHY THAT WORKED, I DON'T UNDERSTAND ?**

QUERY THAT DIDN'T WORK

```
 var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
```

QUERY THAT WORKED of which i don't know how ?

```
var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select new {n.EmplID, n.EmplName}).Distinct();
```

why 2nd worked exactly like i wanted (picking each name 1 time)

i'm using mvc 3 and linq to sql and i am newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries are different. I am explaining you both query in SQL that will help you in understanding both queries.

Your first query is:

```
   var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
```

SQL:-

> SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[EmplID], [t0].[EmplName], [t0].[Dept]
>   FROM [EmployeeAtd] AS [t0]

Your second query is:

```
 (from n in EmployeeAtds select new {n.EmplID, n.EmplName}).Distinct()
```

SQL:-

> SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[EmplID], [t0].[EmplName] FROM [EmployeeAtd] AS
>   [t0]

Now you can see SQL query for both queries. First query is showing that you are implementing Distinct on all columns of table but in second query you are implementing distinct only on required columns so it is giving you desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var names = DataContext.EmployeeAtds.Select(x => x.EmplName).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Update:**

```
var names = DataContext.EmployeeAtds
          .GroupBy(x => x.EmplID)
          .Select(g => new { EmplID = g.Key, EmplName = g.FirstOrDefault().EmplName })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: woww sir, it worked too but my question is that why it is working and why doesn't mine ? elaborate please sir

Comment: Are there any other columns in EmployeeAtd? That they are different for each row?

Comment: You can add other column like my 2nd answer

Comment: ok so in short words, if i use distinct on my whole query then it would search for all column and records and if it finds one mismatch in any record (like not same) then it would return duplicates ? right ? @SamieyMehdi

Answer (score 1):

As per [Scott Allen's Explanation](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/and-equality-for-all-anonymous-types.aspx)

> `var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();`

*The docs for Distinct are clear – the method uses the default equality comparer to test for equality, and the default comparer sees 4 distinct object references. One way to get around this would be to use the overloaded version of Distinct that accepts a custom IEqualityComparer.*

```
var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select new {n.EmplID, n.EmplName}).Distinct();
```

*Turns out the C# compiler overrides Equals and GetHashCode for anonymous types. The implementation of the two overridden methods uses all the public properties on the type to compute an object's hash code and test for equality. If two objects of the same anonymous type have all the same values for their properties – the objects are equal. This is a safe strategy since anonymously typed objects are essentially immutable (all the properties are read-only).*